# ReactJS: How to pass props from WrappedComponent to Higher-Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a higher-order component `FormBuilder` like this:

```
const FormBuilder = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class HOC extends React.Component {
    clearForm() { // ... }

    render() {
      return (
        <Form onSubmit={//what do I say here?!}>
           <Form.Input placeholder='Name' name='name' />
           <WrappedComponent clearForm={this.clearForm} />
        <Form>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the WrappedComponent `NewPizzaForm`:

```
class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() { // sends a POST request to the backend, then this.props.clearForm() }

  render() {
     return (
       <Form.Button>Add Pizza</Form.Button>
     );
  }
}

const NewPizzaForm = FormBuilder(WrappedComponent);

export default NewPizzaForm;
```

So I want to send the `onSubmit` function as a prop from the `WrappedComponent` to the `FormBuilder` so that it is available for call when the form is submitted. And the reason I decided to define the `onSubmit` function inside `WrappedComponent` is because I have another `WrappedComponent`(uses `FormBuilder`) that has the `onSubmit` function but it sends a PATCH request rather than POST request. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Create one method in parent one and call the parent prop when button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want to change or pass anything from the child component to parent, you should use `state`. You'll have `state` in the `Parent` component which will be mutated by the `Child` component with some actions. 
But this is not the case. 
If you always have just that two types of submits you can make it generic, by adding a `prop`/`argument` on your `Parent`/`HOC`, which will tell which kind of submit to use. 
If in the future you will have many type of submits, thus it will not be generic at all, then there is no need to overwhelm the `Parent` component. You can make submit from the `Child` component and pass needed submit function to the `HOC decorator` as an argument. As a good example you can check the [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.0.4/docs/api/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want onSubmit to be defined in WrappedComponent? If I were you, I'd define it in its parent, so that you can pass it to the HOC as a prop. A very common pattern that I've used in forms is to make a form component, say LoginForm, that handles the form logic, then wrap it in a LoginPage that handles the submission logic and all of that. LoginPage passes a handleSubmit/onSubmit prop down to LoginForm, which then calls it when submitted. This also allows you to reuse forms quite easily.

Comment: Let say you also have RegisterForm component that does something different onSubmit. How do you handle that? That is the problem i am facing. I have two different forms: one for editing an information and one for creating a new information. So my `NewPizzaForm` does something clearly different than `EditPizzaForm` when they are submitted.

Comment: Create a shared PizzaForm that handles the form specifics, then a NewPizzaPage and a EditPizzaPage that each have an onSubmit defined. Pass it down to the HOC/the wrapped PizzaForm as a prop.

Comment: That is exactly my original question. How do I pass to the HOC?

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, the HOC is a component too, so you can just pass it to WrappedComponent: <WrappedComponent onSubmit={onSubmit}>, then use it in the HOC.